# How index.html in Angular-CLI .NET Core is called?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, angular-cli

I have built an Angular-CLI .Net Core SPA with Visual Studio 2017 by using

```
dotnet new angular -o my-new-app
```

What I am struggling to find is how `index.html` which lies inside `ClientApp/src` folder is called by default when write e.g.

```
http://localhost:57782
```

**startup.cs** file has as follows:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.AngularCli;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace angular_cli
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            //services.AddMvc();

            // In production, the Angular files will be served from this directory
            services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
            {
                configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist";
            });
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            }

            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseSpaStaticFiles();

            //app.UseMvc(routes =>
            //{
            //    routes.MapRoute(
            //        name: "default",
            //        template: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            //});

            app.UseSpa(spa =>
            {
                // To learn more about options for serving an Angular SPA from ASP.NET Core,
                // see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=864501

                spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

                if (env.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

On purpose, I have disabled MVC middleware and everything works fine. However, I have `no idea by which mechanism and settings index.html is called`... Any good explanations please?

Comment: I expect it's the combination of `configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist";` and webpack.

Answer (score 2):

So I had exactly the same question but for React App (I guess that for angular is very similar). I spent last 2 hours on investigation how things works under the hood and I'm still not quite sure If I'm right but thats what I found out:

### Development

```
spa.UseReactDevelopmentServer(npmScript: "start");
```

1. This method  runs npmScript called `start` - you may find it in `package.json` file in `scripts` section. This script starts [WebPackDevServer](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/) which performs webpack pipeline in memory and then serves generated files also from memory (it allows reloading files in browser quickly and without rebuilding application which is great for development).

Webpack pipeline generate necessary js & css scripts, inject links to those files into index.html and then copy all necessary files into specified directory (or memory in this case ;))

2. It setup proxy to that server so ASP passes all request to that server and ultimately your files are just served from memory.

---

You may also run this server directly from console and instruct ASP to setup proxy to existing server without starting npm script. It may be achieved by using `UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer` method.

### Production

In case of production build the server is not (and should not be) used. The `build` script should be called (by `PublishRunWebpack`step which you can find in `csproj` file) which will run similar pipeline which will produce minified files and proper index.html into specified folder. Then those files will be served directly from HDD thanks to `AddSpaStaticFiles` configuration.

At least this is my current understanding of this process.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it is late for this question, but  I met the same problem to figure out how index.html, which lies inside ClientApp/src folder, is called by http:// localhost:57788, and this is what I found.

According Microsoft's requirement for app.UseSpa method:

> Handles all requests from this point in the middleware chain by
>   returning the default page for the Single Page Application (SPA). This
>   middleware should be placed late in the chain, so that other
>   middleware for serving static files, MVC actions, etc., takes
>   precedence.

That means all requests without registered, valid routes (http:// localhost:57788 does not have any controller, which is necessary according that project's route configuration) will reach and activate app.UseSpa middleware. The Framework to get path to the angular bootstrap Index.html file, first picking from spa.Options.SourcePath property (ClientApp)  folder name , then looking for "baseUrl" in  ClientApp /src/tsconfig.app.json file ("./"), which is the folder where index.html should reside. In case the framework found index.html file in ClientApp/src/ folder sending it to the client.

For verification you can try:
1. if you change src folder name to src_, you will get this error:
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'C:..... \ClientApp\src \tsconfig.app.json'
2. if you change index.htm file name to index__.html you will get this error:
Cannot GET /
3.Request with valid rout: http:// localhost:57788/
SampleData/WeatherForecasts is returning json data.

Answer (score 1):

If you request server directly, you should be served with index.html in 'ClientApp/dist' folder given here:

```
        services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
        {
            configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist";
        });
```

and you are calling that service here:

```
        app.UseSpaStaticFiles();

        app.UseSpa(spa =>
        {
            spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";
```

If you are in development environment which you are, it will use `npm start` command which is equal to `ng serve` in the SourcePath you defined above, to start angular server and proxy requests to angular server. Actually displayed index.html is just on memory and neither in dist folder nor in wwwroot.

```
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

It is provided by Static Files Middleware that is registered by

```
app.UseStaticFiles();
```

You may read about it here: [Work with static files in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x)

Github repo: https://github.com/aspnet/StaticFiles

Comment: No, it is not! I can delete this middleware and everything will work fine. Moreover, `index.html` is not inside the root folder (wwwroot) as to be served as a file

Answer (score -2):

> What I am struggling to find is how index.html which lies inside
>   ClientApp/src folder is called by default when write e.g.

It doesn't use  `index.html`. Instead, it calls `Home` controller's `Index` action method.

`http://localhost:57782` is same as `http://localhost:57782/Home/Index`. It is basically an entry point for the entire application.

You can see it inside `Startup.cs`

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

    routes.MapSpaFallbackRoute(
        name: "spa-fallback",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
});
```

Comment: I appreciate to spend some of your time to answer my query, however if you had a more thorough look at my question you would see that I have disabled MVC and there is no `routes.MapSpaFallbackRoute`.

Comment: I don't think `UseSpa()` will call `Home` controller's `Index`-action. I didn't even have one.
To test your theory, I created one. I will *not* be called. It will call hard-coded `index.html` from `ClientApp/src`.

Comment: The hard-coding is in NodeJS-module _react-scripts_ file `config/paths.js`, it has: `appHtml: resolveApp('public/index.html')`

Answer (score -2):

After the application is published, index.html is added all css and js resources and copied to dist folder. The index.html file is loaded by default. Basically it depends on Default document setting in IIS (on Windows).

Answer (score -3):

I hit the same issue as you and this was the first place I came for an answer.

The solution actually was:

`app.UseDefaultFiles();`

After that hitting http:domain/ served the index.html as expected.

[Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x#serve-a-default-document)